# How to publish values from the main thread using DispatchQueue.global().async?

Tags: swiftui, combine, ios14

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to show a progress status when a flag is true.

In my code, the flag has true status during a `while` loop with a method wrapped in the `DispatchQueue.main.sync` method works.
But I get an error below:

[image]

> Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.

How cloud I solve this problem?

---

Here are the codes:

AppState.swift

```
@Published var isLoading:Bool = false
@Published var weatherInfos:[WeatherInfos]?


func getTemperatureAsync(date: String) {

    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        var counter:Int = 0
        var totalTemp:Float = 0.0

        while counter < 100
        {
            self.isLoading = true // I get error here

            counter += 1
            totalTemp += self.getTemperature(date: date)

            self.isLoading = false // I get error here
        }
    }
}


func getTemperature(date: String) -> Float{

    var temperature: Float = 0.0
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    let endpoint: String = "https://sample.com/api/weather/?&date=\(date)"
    let url = URL(string: endpoint)
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    urlRequest.addValue("token xxxxxxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
    // set up the session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {(data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET")
            return
        }
        // make sure we got data
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            do{
                self.weatherInfos = try JSONDecoder().decode([WeatherInfos].self, from: responseData)

                for info in self.weatherAveInfos!{
                    temperature += info.ave_temp
                }
            }catch{
                print("Error: did not decode")
                return
            }
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    task.resume()
    semaphore.wait()

    return temperature
}
```

JsonModel.swift

```
struct WeatherInfos:Codable,Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var ave_temp: Float
}
```

Progress.swift

```
struct Progress: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProgressView("Loading...")
    }
}
```

MainView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct InformationView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {
       if appState.isLoding {
           Progress()
       }
       Button(action:{
            appState.getTemperatureAsync(date: "2020-11-01")
       }){
            Text("show progress")
         }
    }
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Comment: As an aside, you should eliminate that semaphore in `getTemperature`. That `dataTask` API is asynchronous for a reason, and your app will freeze and will be subject to being killed by the watchdog process if you do this at the wrong time. No semaphores.

Comment: Also unrelated to the question at hand, but if you're going to create a `URLSession` as a local var, you must call `finishTasksAndInvalidate` after you `resume` your task, or else you're going to leak. Or, easier, just use `URLSession.shared` given that you're not doing anything custom in your `URLSession` that requires your own custom instances.

Comment: @Rob, Thank you for your comment, I will check what you advised me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61108947/swiftui-make-sure-to-publish-values-from-the-main-thread-via-operators-like-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispatch your updates back to the main queue. The problem is that you are blocking the main queue with your semaphore, so attempts to dispatch updates back to that blocked thread will lead to a deadlock.

But you should remove that semaphore, regardless. It solves the deadlock risk, but also makes it faster, avoids blocking the UI at all. And you should then adopt asynchronous pattern.

Since this is SwiftUI, I would suggest using Combine for this asynchronous behavior. For example, I might use `dataTaskPublisher` to perform the request:

```
func weatherPublisher(for date: Date) -> AnyPublisher<Float, Error> {
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url(for: date))
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: WeatherReport.self, decoder: decoder)
        .map(\.temperature)
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

And if you want to retrieve the weather for many dates, use a sequence:

```
func weatherSequence(for dates: [Date]) -> AnyPublisher<Float, Error> {
    Publishers.Sequence(sequence: dates.map { self.weatherPublisher(for: $0) })
        .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(4)) { $0 }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

And if you want to average the values:

```
class AverageTemperature: ObservableObject {
    var weatherRequests: AnyCancellable?
    @Published var average: Float = .nan
    private var values: [Float] = []

    func start() {
        let dates = ...
        weatherRequests = weatherSequence(for: dates).sink { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .finished:
                self.average = self.values.reduce(0, +) / Float(self.values.count)

            case .failure(let error):
                print("failed", error)
            }
        } receiveValue: { value in
            self.values.append(value)
        }
    }

    func weatherSequence(for dates: [Date]) -> AnyPublisher<Float, Error> {
        Publishers.Sequence(sequence: dates.map { self.weatherPublisher(for: $0) })
            .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(4)) { $0 }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func weatherPublisher(for date: Date) -> AnyPublisher<Float, Error> {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url(for: date))
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: WeatherReport.self, decoder: decoder)
            .map(\.temperature)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func url(for date: Date) -> URL {
        var components = URLComponents(string: endPoint)!
        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "date", value: formatter.string(from: date))
        ]
        return components.url!
    }
}
```

Now, I know my example is different from yours (my example assumes the endpoint returns a single temperature and I am averaging the values from the separate API calls), so do not get lost in the details here. But the big picture is:

- Use `dataTaskPublisher` to perform individual requests asynchronously;
- Use `Sequence` to let them all run concurrently, but use `maxPublishers` to constrain the degree of concurrency; and
- Use `sink` to gather the results and do whatever calculations you want.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply, It is the first time to use the `combine` framework and I'll try my best to handle it, Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (there is no much sense reporting `isLoading` in cycle because while iterating it just immediately change false to true again).

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    var counter:Int = 0
    var totalTemp:Float = 0.0

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.isLoading = true
    }

    while counter < 100
    {
        counter += 1
        totalTemp += self.getTemperature(date: date)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.isLoading = false
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried following your code,  there is no error but it doesn't work as I want, the progress appears a little and then disappears immediately...

Comment: Then check how your `getTemperature` works... but it is different topic.