# How to publish change from async function

Tags: swiftui, async-await

I have class conforms to ObservableObject with

```
@Published var fileContent = ""
```

defined. Further I have getFileContent() async function returning String.
If I call function like this

```
Task {
    fileContent = await getFileContent(forMeasurementID: id, inContext: context)
}
```

code is compiled and app works fine but XCode is complaining "purple" error "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.". I've tried to elaborate with receive(on:) but no succeess so far.
I will appreciate any hint. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61108947/swiftui-make-sure-to-publish-values-from-the-main-thread-via-operators-like-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the state of your app (change a `@Published` var) unless you are in the main thread.

Here is how your code works:

```
Task {
    let content = await getFileContent(forMeasurementID: id, inContext: context)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        fileContent = content
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course I can't... so easy... thank you @HunterLion

Answer (score 13):

Well, in async/await world it is better to use MainActor, e.g.

```swift
Task {
    let content = await getFileContent(forMeasurementID: id, inContext: context)
    await MainActor.run {
        // fileContent will be updated on the Main Thread
        fileContent = content
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the actual correct answer, the answer marked as correct does work, but is improper compared to this one.