# SwiftUI - Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to create an app that creates random pictures when a button is clicked. The app is working fine but I see this message which I have never seen before."Publish changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread.".
I am new to SwiftUI, help is appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
  class ImageviewModel{
    var image: UIImage? = nil
    //let url = URL(string: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600")!
    let url = URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/600/600")!
    func responseHandler(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?) ->
    UIImage?{
        guard let data = data,
              let image = UIImage(data: data),
              let response = response else {return nil}
        return image
    }
    func loadImageWithAsync() async throws -> UIImage?{
        do{
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url,delegate: nil)
            return responseHandler(data: data, response: response)
        } catch{
            throw error
        }
    }
}
class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var image: UIImage? = nil
    var loader = ImageviewModel()
    func fetchImage() async {
        let image = try? await loader.loadImageWithAsync()
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `.task`, then you can remove both of those classes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61108947/swiftui-make-sure-to-publish-values-from-the-main-thread-via-operators-like-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `MainActor` wrapper to the class to guarantee that updates are done on Main

```
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
```