# Dismissing view using ObservableObject class provokes Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed

Tags: swiftui, dismiss, observableobject

When dismissing a fullScreenCover using a variable inside an ObservableObject (lines commented with 1.-) it shows the "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior." message in the console, but using a @State variable (lines commented with 2.-) does not show the warning. I do not understand why.

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

final class DismissWarningVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showAnotherView = false
}

struct DismissWarningView: View {
    @StateObject private var dismissWarningVM = DismissWarningVM()
    
    @State private var showAnotherView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    // 1.- This line provokes the warning
                    dismissWarningVM.showAnotherView = true
                    // 2.- This line DO NOT provokes the warning
                    //showAnotherView = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Show")
                }
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 20)
            Spacer()
            Text("Main view")
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.white)
        // 1.- This line provokes the warning
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $dismissWarningVM.showAnotherView) {
        // 2.- This line DO NOT provokes the warning
        //.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showAnotherView) {
            AnotherView()
        }
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("Another view")
            Button {
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Dismiss")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct DismissWarningView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DismissWarningView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75271604/swiftui-publishing-changes-from-background-threads-is-not-allowed)

Comment: No, using @MainActor does not prevent the warning

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. It was a problem of the XCode version. I was trying with 14.0.1 version  but after updating to 14.1 version the warning is no longer shown

Answer (score -3):

`@StateObject` isn't designed for view model objects. In SwiftUI the `View` struct is the view model already you don't another one. Remember SwiftUI is diffing these structs and creating/updating/removing UIView objects automatically for us. If you use view model objects then you'll have `viewModel object -> View struct -> UIView object`  which is a big mess and will lead to bugs. `@StateObject` is designed for when you need a reference type in an `@State` which isn't very often nowadays given we have `.task` and `.task(id:)` for asynchronous features.

You can achieve what you need like this:

```
struct WarningConfig {
    var isPresented = false

    // mutating func someLogic() {} 
}

struct SomeView: View {

    @State private var config = WarningConfig()

    ...

    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $config.isPresented) {
        WarningView(config: $config)
```