# How to avoid SwiftUI warnings about "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed" when using onKeyPress and ObservableObject?

Tags: swiftui, ios17, property-wrapper-published, macos-sonoma

I've been trying to use the new `onKeyPress` functionality in SwiftUI 5. However, updates to a `@Published` property of an Observable Object within the handler produce a warning "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior."

Note I haven't seen anything actually go wrong in practice, but Xcode logs a lot of red warnings in Console and purple runtime issues.

A simple replication; can modify with button or modify local `@State` without the warning; however modifying the `@Published` property from `onKeyPress` produces the warning.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
class ExampleService: ObservableObject {
  @Published var text = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var service = ExampleService()
  
  @State var localText = ""
  
    var body: some View {
      VStack {

        Button {
          // This is fine
          service.text += "!"
        } label: {
          Text("Press Me")
        }
        
        Label("Example Focusable", systemImage: "arrow.right")
          .focusable()
          .onKeyPress { action in
            // XCode whines about "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior."
            service.text += "."
            return .handled
          }
        
        Label("Example Local State", systemImage: "arrow.left")
          .focusable()
          .onKeyPress { action in
            // This is fine
            localText += "."
            return .handled
          }
        
        Text(service.text)
        Text(localText)
      }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: **Correction**, I can replicate the issue. Using `DispatchQueue.main.async { service.text += "." }` does fix it for me.

Comment: RED warnings? Usually these run-time warnings are purple.

Comment: @soundflix yes you are correct/I could have been clearer. Appears as purple issue in Issue Navigator. What I meant was that it shows red warnings in the Console.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine yes that works for me, thank you. A bit ugly/unfortunate on Apple's API part if this is always required (and I'd still like to understand why it is required). If you want to make that an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Exactly the same problem for me. I made the warnings disappear using a Task. I guess it’s related to how the responder chain handles the events and that it will go away in the next releases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61108947/swiftui-make-sure-to-publish-values-from-the-main-thread-via-operators-like-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the warning disappear, use

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {  
    service.text += "." 
}
```

that will ensure the UI update is carried out on the main thread, as required by SwiftUI. Note, as mentioned in the comments you can also use `Task{...}`.

As I understand it, `@MainActor` is supposed to make execution on the main queue,
but (I guess) not always. See this proposal to remove it from Swift 6:
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0401-remove-property-wrapper-isolation.md

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach (and probably what Apple want us to do now) is using `@Observable`

```swift
// No warnings in Xcode
@Observable class CompletionState {
  var text = ""
}

// Purple warnings in Xcode
class CompletionState2: ObservableObject {
  @Published var text = ""
}
```

It seems given Observable also offers more fine grained reactivity it is basically the preferred approach anyway. I've found updating an existing app was surprisingly straightforward. [Apple have a guide on doing this here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro).